# Monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $(M,\otimes)$ be a small symmetric monoidal category.
Is it possible to choose in each isomorphy class $[A]$ a representative $A_0$ and for each $A\in M$ an isomorphism $\phi_A:A\to A_0$ in a way that for any $A,B\in M$ the equation
$$
\phi_{A\otimes B}=\phi_{A\otimes B_0}\circ(1\otimes\phi_B)
$$
holds?

Comment: I would try disproving that claim by taking the category to be the strict 2-group with two elements, each element with an automorphism group $\mathbb Z/2$ and all that equipped with the non-trivial associator $\alpha\in H^3(\mathbb Z/2,\mathbb Z/2)$.

Comment: Sorry... this is not symmetric monoidal.

Comment: Have you tried the category of finitely generated projective $R$-modules?